# Поиск по элементам listView

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

Я добавила в `ListView` элементы и сделала переходы, при нажатии на них, на другие активити. А как мне реализовать поиск по этим элементам?

```
final String[] listview_names = {"один","два",три","четыре","пять"}; //мой массив
```

мой лэйаут в котором хочу поиск сделать

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=""
        android:text="@string/search" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EditText01"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Не знаю, важно это или нет, но я делаю приложение из 3 фрагментов

Comment: Вот так я сделала переходы
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int position, long arg3)
       {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), one.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }        }   });

Comment: извините что не в тему но где Вы все учитесь, что у всех одна и таже задача, с запуском активити из LsiView? у вас должны быть хоть какие-то внутренние поля по которым в этом списке можно осуществлять поиск. что вы хотите искать с помощью данного поиска. а еще лучше выдайте вашу задачу в студию пожалуйста, проще будет обсудить и подсказать правильное направление.

Comment: У меня будут поля, с названием различных разделов. Сверху я поместила поле для ввода текста,я хочу чтобы при вводе текста отсортировывалось то, что у меня в листвью. оставались подходящие строки

Comment: как вы храните разделы? в чем? у вас есть отдельные сущности или это просто массив строк соответствующих названиям разделов?

Comment: мне интереснее где вообще учат android ? у нас максимум чему учат это делфи и билдер (